# MongoDB returning result even though the filter is false?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, filter

I am trying to fetch data based on filters which are: if the timestamp is between 08:00:00 and 16:00:00 for a specific date, it should return results. $gte than 16:00:00 filter is working fine, but not $lte.

TIMESTAMP OF work.time.work_time.start_time is = 1680940800000

TIMESTAMP OF requestBooking.booking.estimated_start_time is = 1680919200000

here is the code: (it should fail, but somehow it is not failing).

```js
      const bookingObject = await this.bookingRepository.findOne({
        user_id: body.worker_id,
        'work.date': requestBooking.booking.date,
        'work.time.work_time.start_time': {
          $lte: requestBooking.booking.estimated_start_time,
        },
        'work.time.work_time.end_time': {
          $gte: requestBooking.booking.estimated_start_time + 1800000, // +30 min after
        },
      });
```

Comment: If you swap `"$lte"` and `"$gte"` in your query, does it return the document you want?

Comment: Nope. Swapping it means it will work for all given times, beside from 08:00 -> 16:00

Comment: Assuming all of those variables have values, that looks like a valid query.  Can we see some sample documents?  Like what doument is it returning that you thing it shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the operator in an incorrect way, you want timestamps in a range so, `start_time` should be greater than equal to, and `end_time` should be less than equal to. Try this:

```
const bookingObject = await this.bookingRepository.findOne({
        user_id: body.worker_id,
        'work.date': requestBooking.booking.date,
        'work.time.work_time.start_time': {
          $gte: requestBooking.booking.estimated_start_time,
        },
        'work.time.work_time.end_time': {
          $lte: requestBooking.booking.estimated_start_time + 1800000, // +30 min after
        },
      });
```

Comment: As I answered the other guy, swapping $lte and $gte does the opposite. whatever value I use in 'work.time.work_time.start_time' whether it's $lte or $gte, it still queries the data outside the range.

Comment: Can you add some sample documents in the question?